# Theme's Js and Css not loading after SSL enabled

Tags: wordpress

I installed the SSL certificate. I changed the WordPress URL and site  URL to https in general setting. But the theme js file and CSS file still working on the Http. And it's showing me the mixed content error.

Answer (score 1):

**Most SSL issues are due to plugins/themes using the wrong code to load CSS/JS.**

- Under WordPress General Settings change the WordPress Address (URL) and the Site Address (URL) from HTTP to HTTPS. If you don't have access to your admin you can change this via your wp-config.php http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
- Use the proper url paths for your themes and plugins: http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories for example hardcoding the WP_PLUGIN_URL will not work as opposed to plugin_dir_url. The functions are generally SSL friendly because they have time to check if the site is SSL enabled, the constants are not.
- For the admin/login you can force SSL via the wp-config.php:

  Login: define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);

  Admin: define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

Of course any hardcoded assets will be a problem or plugins/themes that incorrectly load assets.

You can also update your themes and plugins via SSL if your server has libssh2 , you can also define the port# and Auth keys. If this is enabled you do not have to define anything it will just magically show up in the admin settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. static URL defined in the header file.

Thanks